# Is there a necessary form of consecutive composites?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For every $n \geq 3$ there is a tuple of $n-1$ consecutive composites, namely the composites of the form $n! + 2, \dots, n!+n$. However, must a tuple of $n$ consecutive composites take the form? It seems plausible to me, and I have not yet seen a counterexample.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Take any odd composite number. It is surrounded by two even numbers, so you have a run of 3 consecutive composites there, not necessarily of this form. Are you asking about the smallest occurrence of such a run? This is the first time the gap between two consecutive primes is large enough.

Comment: Assuming that you want to see general recipes producing arbitrarily long runs of composite you can use [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) the same way that factorials are used. So the numbers $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7+k$ are all composite when $k=2,3,\ldots,11-1$. Similarly $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11+k$ are all composite when $k=2,3,\ldots,13-1$. I doubt this gives anywhere near the smallest runs of a given length in general.

Answer (score 3):

No, we can find consecutive composites that are not of this form. The point of $n!$ is just that it is a "very divisible number". We can obtain a lost of many other examples just like this one.

For example the numbers $n!^2+2,n!^2+4\dots +n!^2+n$ or $n!^3+2,n!^3+3\dots n!^3+2$.

Also $kn!+2,kn!+3\dots k!n+n$ works for all $k>0\in\mathbb Z$

You can also get a smaller examples if instead of using $n!$ we use the least common multiple of the numbers between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you!

Comment: So must the consecutive composites be involved with factorials?

Comment: no, you can take any number that is "very divisible" and the same trick works.

Comment: Chou: primorials work just as well. By using the PNT you get that there are $n$ consecutive composite numbers less than $e^{(1+\varepsilon)n}$.